# I have navbar in react, when I click link and open it in new tab, then it gives 404 error

Tags: reactjs

https://conference.icghgd.com/

Tech Stack: React

I have hosted this website through hostinger. When you click on any navbar link and open it in new tab, then it will give 404 error, if you simply click then it works. Why is it so?
I tried to test it by hosting through vercel. On vercel it is completely fine.
So i guess there is some issue in hostinger only? can anybody help me out?
On localhost also it works perfectly fine.

Vercel link: https://conference-7ok59iln6-preet-sojitra.vercel.app/

Comment: Probably you need to configure the hostinger server to serve the app on all routes, not only the root `"/"` route but also everything that matches `"/*"`.
Reason it works if you simply click it is because after the app is loaded, react-router takes command on navigation.

Comment: So I can configure by editing htaccess file?

Comment: Im not familiar with hostinger configuration